# Does postgres guarantee that a unique UUID is generated for a column with a unique constraint and a random UUID default?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

Given a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE the_table (
  the_uuid UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
  -- more columns
);
```

If we insert a row without a value for the `the_uuid` column, and the DBMS generates a random UUID, does postgres seamlessly handle the unlikely scenario where it generates a UUID that already exists within the column?

One would imagine that postgres could just retry the random UUID generation until it gets a UUID that does not violate the constraint. But if postgres is not implemented this way, one would need to handle this externally.

For numeric types, we have the idea of a `SEQUENCE` that solves this to an extent, but I'm not aware of an analog for the `UUID` type.

Many readers of this question will want to comment or answer that I am worrying about something that is vanishingly unlikely to happen, and I agree, but I am still interested in better understanding the ways postgres may handle this.

Comment: In the unlikely event that `gen_random_uuid()` generates a value that is already in the database, a "duplicate key" violation will be thrown. A `sequence` does **not** solve that problem btw.

Comment: There won't be specific code to handle collisions *because* of how unlikely it is to generate one. Any time spent engineering a solution to it is wasted time. Remember - you have to generate 1 billion type 4 UUIDs per second for 85 years to get a better than 50% chance of generating two the same.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How do you mean "A sequence does not solve that problem"? It does solve it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I totally get your point. I guess if the postgres devs did not implement a defence against this scenario, I probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @rosmak: you can insert into the table bypassing the sequence generation. The next time you take the value from the sequence you'll have exactly the same problem. In the end you'll have to deal with "duplicate key" errors one way or the other.

Comment: That's a great question. Also "vanishingly unlikely to happen" usually means chasing primary key violations that occur once in a blue moon and have to be dealt with in client code.

Answer (score 1):

According to an [answer in DBA stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214089), no there is no guarantee.

I don't want to plagiarize the answer and copy it here but the poster seems to be providing a convincing example to demonstrate the behavior. I didn't try it myself though.